# Risk Neutral Density Curve for SPY Options looks very weird

Tags: options, option-pricing, risk-neutral-measure

I have created a risk neutral density curve using SPY weekly options and the RND package in R. I calculated the risk neutral density for the Feb07 options. The curve looks very weird when I look at the 280-350 strikes (spot at 321.75). I thought I would have seen some negative skew here. 
The function extracts the mixture of three lognormals from American options.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my reproducible R code with the data (puts, calls, strikes)

```
library(RND)

data = structure(list(puts = c(0.065, 0.075, 0.095, 0.1, 0.115, 0.125, 
0.135, 0.145, 0.155, 0.16, 0.155, 0.165, 0.185, 0.195, 0.205, 
0.22, 0.225, 0.245, 0.265, 0.285, 0.325, 0.35, 0.355, 0.395, 
0.455, 0.505, 0.575, 0.615, 0.655, 0.735, 0.845, 0.955, 1.085, 
1.16, 1.235, 1.395, 1.575, 1.78, 2.015, 2.135, 2.26, 2.54, 2.84, 
3.17, 3.535, 3.705, 3.92, 4.35, 4.83, 5.355, 5.94, 6.255, 6.58, 
7.305, 8.07, 8.915, 9.895, 10.365, 10.76, 11.74, 12.72, 13.73, 
14.725, 15.23, 15.73), strike = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 
26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 
42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 
58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65), calls = c(52.425, 47.45, 42.47, 
39.98, 37.49, 35.005, 32.52, 31.525, 30.535, 30.04, 29.54, 28.55, 
27.575, 26.575, 25.59, 25.095, 24.605, 23.625, 22.65, 21.68, 
20.715, 20.235, 19.755, 18.8, 17.85, 16.91, 15.975, 15.51, 15.05, 
14.12, 13.24, 12.34, 11.47, 11.045, 10.62, 9.795, 8.975, 8.185, 
7.4, 7.035, 6.65, 5.94, 5.235, 4.56, 3.915, 3.615, 3.31, 2.74, 
2.22, 1.74, 1.325, 1.145, 0.97, 0.67, 0.445, 0.285, 0.165, 0.125, 
0.1, 0.065, 0.035, 0.025, 0.015, 0.015, 0.015)), row.names = c(NA, 
65L), na.action = structure(66:91, .Names = c("66", "67", "68", 
"69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", 
"80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", 
"91"), class = "omit"), class = "data.frame")

dens = extract.am.density(r = .016, te = 5/252, s0 = 321.75, market.calls = data$calls,
                          market.puts = data$puts, strikes = data$strike,
                          lambda = 1)

x = seq(from = 280, 350, by = 1)
y = dmln.am(x, u.1 = dens$u.1, 
            u.2 = dens$u.2, 
            u.3 = dens$u.3,
            sigma.1 = dens$sigma.1,
            sigma.2 = dens$sigma.2,
            sigma.3 =  dens$sigma.3,
            p.1 = dens$p.1, 
            p.2 = dens$p.2)


 plot(y ~ x, type = "l", col = "red")
```

[image]